# open url's having "# " in them (Selenium webdriver)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a URL like https://abc.xyz.net/#/abcdef/1-2-3.

```
String url = "https://abc.xyz.net/#/abcdef/1-2-3"
```

When trying to open it using `driver.get(url)`, its opening only till `"https://abc.xyz.net/#/"` and the remaining part is not evaluated or getting truncated.

Can someone please help me how to resolve it. I am using Java + Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: The [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) identfier `#` is the last part of the url. so any portion of url after this won't be sent to server.

Comment: but portion after "#" is absolutely important for me to open the required page

Comment: could you give some more details on the action you want to perform on the part after # ? or any example url you have ?

Comment: reference number mentioned after the "#" opens the required page on which i need to make changes. ex: https://abc.xyz.net/#/orderinformation/1-2-3

Comment: can't you access it without # ?

Comment: its giving 404 error without "#"

Comment: can you share url ?

Comment: sorry i cannot share url but its exactly in the format i shared above,

Comment: May be check properties of the url to see any other redirected url

Answer (score 0):

thanks Prany for your time. 
The issue is due to the fragment identifier "#" in the url. I am able to resolve it by using JavascriptExecutor.