# Selenium chromedriver unable to locate href tag nested inside class tags

Tags: java, html, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using `selenium` web-driver, I want to capture or click on
this HTML tag as

`\<a class="sub-nav-link style-scope app-shell active" href="#/trend-analysis/tag-search"\>`

I tried using
`Driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[@href='#/trend-analysis/tag-search']")).click();`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse style-scope app-shell" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="app-nav navbar-nav mr-auto style-scope app-shell">
                    <li class="nav-item style-scope app-shell">
                        <a class="nav-link p-3 px-4 style-scope app-shell" href="/#/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item style-scope app-shell">
                        <a class="nav-link py-3 px-4 style-scope app-shell active" href="/#/trend-analysis/tag-search">Trend
                            Analysis</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap list-unstyled style-scope app-shell">
                            <li class="sub-nav-item style-scope app-shell">
                                <a class="sub-nav-link style-scope app-shell active" href="#/trend-analysis/tag-search">
                                    Trend Analysis
                                </a>
```

**error**

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@href='/#/trend-analysis/tag-search']"}
```

my guess is that it doesn't detect this href because its buried deep under many `<a>` and `<class>` tags. Please guide me.

**new error**
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='nav-item style-scope app-shell']/a[contains(@href,'#/trend-analysis/tag-search')]"}

with
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='nav-item style-scope app-shell']/a[contains(@href,'#/trend-analysis/tag-search')]")).click();`

Comment: Try driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.sub-nav-link.style-scope.app-shell.active")).click()

Answer (score 1):

Actually in your answer you dont have the first "is this the problem????

because this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#/trend-analysis/tag-search']")).click();
```

seems to be working well

if the problem is the # as the guy below sais maybe this will fix it:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='nav-item style-scope app-shell']/a[contains(@href,'#/trend-analysis/tag-search')]")).click();
```

WISH I HELPED

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='nav-item style-scope app-shell']/a[contains(@href,'#/trend-analysis/tag-search')]"}

Comment: i already shown you error both original now the new one, it just doesn't detect the element

Comment: Ok can you send a link because maybe there is something going on with frames on the website the xpath is not wrong and this issue doesn’t come from the #

Comment: the application is sensitive and beside it requires a user-login, I can send you a particular code (HTML) if you..

Comment: its written in python flask, java + node.js

Comment: pls see my updated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067016/selenim-chrome-driver-unable-to-locate-nested-li-tags/64072239#64072239

Answer (score 0):

This probably qualifies as NAA (Not an answer), but I don't have the reputation to post comments... You can delete it, I won't be offended.

I parse `# URL's` everyday.  If you will look at the following [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031620/open-urls-having-in-them-selenium-webdriver), you will see a little bit about using the `#` inside of a **`URL`** with Selenium.

**NOTE:** The typical purpose of a **`#`** in a **`URL`** is to make a *self-referential-link* which means that the **`URL`** usually points to the exact same **`URL`** as the page you are currently looking at - but, precisely, to a different location on the page.

If the **`URL`** or **`HREF`** you are trying to located using the **`X-Path`** statement in your code using **`Selenium`** has both a **`#`** and more forward-slash **`/dirs...`** characters in it, according to [this web-site](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling), Java-Script (AJAX) is being invoked, and perhaps **`Selenium`** is not seeing the **`HREF`** the way your **`X-Path`** statement thinks it is supposed to look like.

Salient excerpt from linked site:

> When http://mywebsite.com/#/page1 is accessed it will perform an ajax
> request to our traditional url http://mywebsite.com/page1 fetch the
> HTML of that page, and load in the page's content into our existing
> page.

Long story short: You **`X-Path`** has a **`#`** pound-sign in it, which means it is a 'special-type' of **`URL`** which might need a special-type of **`X-Path`**... (which is an answer I actually can't provide, cuz I don't know :)